# connecting to remote mssql from linux plesk via php

Tags: sql-server, linux, plesk

I am trying to connect to remote Microsoft SQL server 2012 service pack 2 database from my Linux machine which is having php 5.3,  php-mssql support and mysql version 5.5 enabled.  Meanwhile I am getting below error message even if the login details are correct.

The ms-sql database is using Persian collation which cannot be changed.  Is there any possible fix for this?

[root@i]#  /usr/bin/tsql  -H remove-server-ip -p 1433 -U mssql-user

locale is "en_IN"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 4075 (severity 16, state 1) from RAHKARAN Line 1:
    "

> The USE database statement failed because the database collation
>   Persian_100_CI_AI is not recognized by older client drivers. Try
>   upgrading the client operating system or applying a service update to
>   the database client software, or use a different collation. See SQL
>   Server Books Online for more information on changing collations."

Msg 18456 (severity 14, state 1) from RAHKARAN Line 1:
    "Login failed for user 'mssql-user'."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server

> Error 20002 (severity 9)

Freetds version is below

tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes

Comment: Try to create issue in FreeTDS project https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds and maybe newer versions like 0.95 or even 1.0 can help you.

Comment: submitted the same in github. Link is below
https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/issues/74